# Is it off-topic to ask "Has there been a study of subject X?"?

Tags: support

I'd like to ask whether there's been any theoretical study of circuits where the nodes take arrays of a uniform type, or vectors in high-dimensional vector spaces, rather than boolean values.

However I can't tell, from reading the 'Tour', whether that would be on-topic or not. On some SX sites this might be considered an unacceptable "shopping" question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're clear about what you're asking and show that you've thought about it, questions like this should be on-topic.